# MongoDB count total number of tweets on weekdays and weekends (Python)

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, pymongo

I have a collection of 24.8 million documents (tweet objects). Each tweet object represents single tweet. Example of a tweet object:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5ff0798da1fb5219b93ef4ca'),
 'tweet_id': 1233904784635256833,
 'user_id': 1092190045,
 'user_followers_count': 1653,
 'user_friends_count': 24,
 'user_tweets_count': 62340,
 'user_mentions': [],
 'coordinates': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [13.435, 52.481388]},
 'created_at': 'Sun Mar 01 00:00:00 +0000 2020',
 'lang': 'de',
 'text': 'schepper'}
```

I want to find the total number of tweets on weekdays (Mon - Fri) and weekends (Sat and Sun).

I tried this:

```
tweets_by_weekday = [{
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "day": {
                     "$dayOfWeek": "created_at"
                }
            },
            "count":{"$sum":1}
        }
    }]
list(tweetsData.aggregate(tweets_by_weekday))
```

Comment: Storing date/time values as **string** is a design flaw. Store them properly as `Date` object, then `_id: { $dayOfWeek: "$created_at" }` will work (note the missing `$` in your code)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
search_request = { "$or": 
    [
        { "created_at": { "$regex": "^Mon .*" } },
        { "created_at": { "$regex": "^Tue .*" } },
        { "created_at": { "$regex": "^Wed .*" } },
        { "created_at": { "$regex": "^Thu .*" } },
        { "created_at": { "$regex": "^Fri .*" } }
    ]
}

mycol.find(search_request).count() #Older pymongo
mycol.count_documents(search_request) #Newer pymongo
```

and:

```
search_request = { "$or": 
    [
        { "created_at": { "$regex": "^Sat .*" } },
        { "created_at": { "$regex": "^Sun .*" } }
    ]
}

mycol.find(search_request).count() #Older pymongo
mycol.count_documents(search_request) #Newer pymongo
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
tweetsData.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,d:{$substr:["$created_at",0,3]}}} , {$group:{_id:"$d" ,cnt:{$sum:1}  }    }  ])
{ "_id" : "Sat", "cnt" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Sun", "cnt" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Thu", "cnt" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Wed", "cnt" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Tue", "cnt" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Fri", "cnt" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Mon", "cnt" : 1 }
```

and distributed by weekends & working days:

```
tweetsData.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,d:{$substr:["$created_at",0,3]}}} , {$group:{_id:"$d" ,cnt:{$sum:1}  } } , {$facet:{ "weekends":[ {$match:{_id:{$in:['Sat','Sun'  ]}}}  ,{$group:{_id:"weekends" , total:{$sum:"$cnt"}}} ],"week":[ {$match:{_id:{$in:['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri']}  } } , {$group:{_id:"week" , total:{$sum:"$cnt"}}} ]  } } ])
{ "weekends" : [ { "_id" : "weekends", "total" : 2 } ], "week" : [ { "_id" : "week", "total" : 5 } ] }
```